# Converting units, ternary phase diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, units, phase-diagram

I have a task with a ternary phase diagram with units given in mol/mol, but in the description I am also given a feed-to-solvent ratio at 2.5 kg/kg. The molecular masses (and in the equation you see below, the small $w$ is the load and the big $W$ the concentration)

$$W_i = \frac{w_i}{1-w_i}$$

are also known.
I tried to use the equation

$n=$$\frac{m}{M}$

for each of the masses and divided them to get the molar ration, but I don't think it is that easy. Could you please explain me how to do this?

Comment: Hello user190233 and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This seems to be a homework question. Please show some more of your work and ask about a specific conceptual problem you are having instead of asking us to do the problem for you. Thanks!

Comment: Hello heather, in no way I am trying to have others do my work. I just don't know if have to use the equation in image 1 or the division with the molar masses is enough to have the ratio turned into mol/mol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to convert mole fractions to mass fractions.  If the mole fractions are $x_i$ and the mass fractions are $w_i$, then if you take as a basis 1 mole total, then the masses of the various species in this one mole are $M_ix_i$ and the total mass is $\sum{M_jx_j}$.  So the mass fractions are given by $$w_i=\frac{M_ix_i}{\sum{M_jx_j}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it with your equation and I come to a molar feed-to-solvent ratio of 2,60. I guess this could be right, because the molar masses are nearly identical (only a difference of 4 g/mol).